# jQuery ajax and .done() as a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

So I am using Node, Cheerio and mongoose to scrape data and then directly post the scraped data in the home page, so I have a button that suppose to use ajax to get the data using /scrape route and once .done, to post the articles to the home page

```
$("#scraper").on("click", function() {
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/scrape"
}).done(function() {
    $("#artWell").empty();
    $.getJSON("/articles", function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
            $("#artWell").append("<p data-id='" + data[i]._id + "'>" + data[i].title + "<br />" + data[i].link + "</p>");
        }
     });
  });
});
```

But I am having is that I have to hit the button #**scraper** twice t get the data posted, as the .done is not responding properly.

Comment: Why you don't do that in the success callback of ajax ?

Comment: Which version of jQuery is that? Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and as @SurenSrapyan suggested, use success callback

Comment: This should work in the single click itself. Verify this by checking the calls made in the browser network tab. You are doing a "GET" initially but not using/capturing any response returned from that REST api though... or by any chance you are creating that _articles_ JSON in the first call and then trying to read it in the `$.getJSON("/articles"..` ?